# Is it possible to have an autofill combobox (within a datagridview) that also provides a dropdown list of all database items in a column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, autofill

So I have a `DataGrid` that uses data from a *MySQL* database. I'm trying to make it so that when the user start's typing in the "Items" column the box will autofill/suggest/append as well as allow for a dropdown list of all the elements within a column of the database.

So far I've either managed to provide the *autofill* feature **OR** the *dropdown list*. **I can't seem to get both of them to work together**. I started wondering if it's even possible, and I have yet to find a solution.

Thus, I made this post. If anyone has any advice that would be helpful. Below are a few of the functions I used to do autofill and dropdown list.

```
     private void invoice_DG_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        string titleText = invoice_DG.Columns[1].HeaderText;
        if (titleText.Equals("ITEM"))
        {
            ComboBox autoText = e.Control as ComboBox;
            /*if (autoText != null)
            {              
                autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                //AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = get_From_Database();
                //autoText.Items.Add(get_From_Database());                    
            }*/

            if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
            {
                autoText.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                autoText.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = get_From_Database();
            }
        }
    }

    private AutoCompleteStringCollection get_From_Database()
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection Coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        string querySelect = "SELECT * FROM Items";
        MySqlCommand commandSelect = new MySqlCommand(querySelect, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string type = reader.ToString();
            Coll.Add(type); //data inserted in collection so that it will be autocomplete when you type keywords
            if (list_Loaded == false)
            {
                string item = reader.GetString("name");
                ITEM.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }            reader.Close();
        list_Loaded = true;


        return Coll;
    }
```

**NOTE** These functions are **changing** and may not reflect what is to ultimately be accepted. This is just their *current state*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make it so that when the user start's typing in the "Items" column the box will autofill/suggest/**append** as well as allow for a dropdown list of all the elements within a column of the database.
>
> So far I've either managed to provide the autofill feature OR the dropdown list. **I can't seem to get both of them to work together**

The important thing here is that you wish the user to have the ability to **append**.  Therefor the drop-down control must **not** be a **drop-down list** as that will prevent users from entering something that isn't already present in the list.  I suggest you change it to a *regular* **drop-down** control.

The typical flow is that you:

1. display the drop-down control after the first key-press and begin populating the dropdown with values (whether that comes from a DB is incidental) filtered on what the user has typed.  If there are no matches then this is the start of a new entry and so the entered character becomes a new entry in the list
2. As more and more characters are entered continue to filter OR append the characters to the new entry (from #1)
3. When they press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/focus away, select the matched filtered record OR if it was a new entry save appropriately (in this case to the DB)

You can see this sort of pattern very easily in Visual Studio with a C# file open and watching how the auto-complete aspect of Intellisense works with C#'s `dynamic` keyword.  Normally C# auto-complete kind of prevents you from auto-completing a method call if that method is not recognised.

`dynamic` auto-complete acts differently in that it makes no assumptions and by default offers no potential members.  However, it does have the concept of **adding**.

```
dynamic something = // get a reference to some object
something.Foo ();   // Intellisense won't offer the Foo() suggestion.  
                    // It won't result as a compile error either
```

However if we attempt the same method call again in the **same** method scope Intellisense steps in and shows us that the method we called before `Foo()` (at least at coding-time) is available.  Of course we won't know for sure until runtime.

```
something.Foo();  // Foo() NOT available in auto-complete
something.Foo();  // Foo() now available in auto-complete
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful bit of information, I may just have to have either/or in this situation. I'm building an invoice application for someone and while I wanted to have the option available for a drop down list, I see that it's probably easier just to get it one way or the other. I'm pretty sure the "client" won't mind either way anyway. Just trying to provide the most applicable functionality that I can. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3448576 not a problem good sir.  Thanks for the vote.  See how you go, remember if its a slightly `different` scenario where this answer doesn't match feel free to post a new question